# Can I attach a bidet washlet with the T-Valve connected to the wall instead of the tank?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

I recently purchased a bidet seat/washlet.  I live in NYC in a rented apartment, and the toilet is designed in such a way to be fairly shallow - and inflow tube to the toilet tank is very hard to reach.

The [instructions](https://www.brondell.com/media/wysiwyg/bidet-attachment/ss150-manual-final-web.pdf) for my bidet seat said explicitly not to install the t-valve on the wall juncture, but instead the juncture between the tube and the toilet tank, and so I attempted to do so.

While I was able to attach the bidet (via the t-valve) to the tank, I could not get it without it leaking, nor could I reinstall the toilet connector to the tank without that leaking.  After several hours of trying, I called my Super who also had no success, and who eventually called a plumber who came the next day and reconnected the toilet without the bidet attachment.  (He, I think, replace a plastic piece that went from the toilet tank to the connector with a longer/new one? But not sure).

Is it possible/advisable to try again, but attach the t-valve to the wall side of the toilet water connector? Do I need a different kind of t-valve for this application?

Thank you, and please let me know if pictures or any other information would be helpful

Edit 1 - Adding photos:
[image: Wall outlet]
[image: Tank Entry]

Comment: A picture of both junctions would be very helpful.

Comment: @JACK thank you for the feedback, have added photos of the wall outlet and the tank outlet

Comment: Please excuse the dust & dirt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to it but you'll need to make a trip to your home store and get a 3/8 x 3/8 x 3/8 fitting similar to the one shown below from Home Depot. Remove the tube from the valve by the wall and screw your new fitting into the valve. Then screw the tube from the toilet into the new fitting and then screw the tube from your bidet into the new fitting. I always bring any fitting I'm working with to the store with me to make sure everything fits...  (that's the cleanest back of toilet I've ever seen)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JACK! I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I've accepted and will try this out.  I appreciate your help